# TensorFlow: out of memory depends on data size

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dummy model (a linear autoencoder). When training on a dataset of 1 000 records, it works; but on a larger dataset, three orders of magnitude larger, it runs out of GPU memory; even though the batch size is fixed and the computer has enough RAM to hold.

Am I doing something silly?

Note: it works fine on TF 2.5, but crashes on TF 2.6-2.9. It always works if training on CPU.

The model is:

```
def get_model(n_inputs: int) -> models.Model:
    inp = layers.Input(shape=(n_inputs,))

    out = layers.Dense(n_inputs, activation='linear')(inp)
    m = models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
    m.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    m.summary()
    return m
```

I am feeding the data through the `tf.data` API

```
    def wrap_data(data: np.ndarray) -> tf.data.Dataset:
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)
        shuffled = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=len(data), reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
        batched = shuffled.batch(16, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE, deterministic=False)
        autoencoder = batched.map(lambda x: (x, x)).prefetch(5)

        return autoencoder
```

The full reproducing script is [here.](https://gist.github.com/Dapid/c876d6d634ec4454edfdae5c16a4cdb2) Running `python benchmark.py` works, but `python benchmark.py --big` doesn't.

I am using Python 3.9 on Fedora 36. The GPU is a Nvidia RTX 2070 with 8 GiB of RAM. The driver version is 515.48.07 and CUDA Version: 11.7. `nvidia-smi` reports most of the memory is available between runs, and the small version requires less than 800 MiB.

The full traceback is:

```
2022-09-05 15:29:37.525261: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:82] Allocation of 16384000000 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
2022-09-05 15:29:54.002629: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:479] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 15.26GiB (rounded to 16384000000)requested by op _EagerConst
If the cause is memory fragmentation maybe the environment variable 'TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async' will improve the situation. 
Current allocation summary follows.
Current allocation summary follows.
2022-09-05 15:29:54.002987: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:491] *_******____________________________________________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/david/[path]/benchmark.py", line 49, in <module>
    main(parser.parse_args().big)
  File "/home/david/[path]/benchmark.py", line 40, in main
    train_data_iterator = wrap_data(train_data)
  File "/home/david/[path]/benchmark.py", line 33, in wrap_data
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 809, in from_tensor_slices
    return TensorSliceDataset(tensors, name=name)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 4551, in __init__
    element = structure.normalize_element(element)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/util/structure.py", line 125, in normalize_element
    ops.convert_to_tensor(t, name="component_%d" % i, dtype=dtype))
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py", line 183, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1640, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_conversion_registry.py", line 48, in _default_conversion_function
    return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 267, in constant
    return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 279, in _constant_impl
    return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 304, in _constant_eager_impl
    t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 102, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.
```

And specifying the GPU memory allocator, as suggested, doesn't help:

```
2022-09-05 15:33:19.542433: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:82] Allocation of 16384000000 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
2022-09-05 15:33:25.973935: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_cudamallocasync_allocator.cc:288] gpu_async_0 cuMemAllocAsync failed to allocate 16384000000 bytes: CUDA error: out of memory (CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY)
 Reported by CUDA: Free memory/Total memory: 1115357184/8369799168
2022-09-05 15:33:25.973961: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_cudamallocasync_allocator.cc:293] Stats: Limit:                      6221922304
InUse:                        67126312
MaxInUse:                    201327628
NumAllocs:                          13
MaxAllocSize:                 67108864
Reserved:                            0
PeakReserved:                        0
LargestFreeBlock:                    0

2022-09-05 15:33:25.973970: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_cudamallocasync_allocator.cc:56] Histogram of current allocation: (allocation_size_in_bytes, nb_allocation_of_that_sizes), ...;
2022-09-05 15:33:25.973974: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_cudamallocasync_allocator.cc:59] 4, 5
2022-09-05 15:33:25.973976: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_cudamallocasync_allocator.cc:59] 8, 2
2022-09-05 15:33:25.973979: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_cudamallocasync_allocator.cc:59] 1028, 1
2022-09-05 15:33:25.973982: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_cudamallocasync_allocator.cc:59] 16384, 1
2022-09-05 15:33:25.973985: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_cudamallocasync_allocator.cc:59] 67108864, 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/david/[path]/benchmark.py", line 48, in <module>
    main(parser.parse_args().big)
  File "/home/david/[path]/benchmark.py", line 40, in main
    train_data_iterator = wrap_data(train_data)
  File "/home/david/[path]/benchmark.py", line 33, in wrap_data
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 809, in from_tensor_slices
    return TensorSliceDataset(tensors, name=name)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 4551, in __init__
    element = structure.normalize_element(element)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/util/structure.py", line 125, in normalize_element
    ops.convert_to_tensor(t, name="component_%d" % i, dtype=dtype))
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py", line 183, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1640, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_conversion_registry.py", line 48, in _default_conversion_function
    return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 267, in constant
    return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 279, in _constant_impl
    return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 304, in _constant_eager_impl
    t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/ainet/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 102, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.
```

Update: [bug report](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/16997)

Comment: I'm wondering if specifying buffer_size=len(data) when shuffling might cause memory usage to increase linearly with the size of the training dataset. You could try setting this parameter to a fixed number, at the cost of not getting a complete random shuffle of the datatset each time through.

Comment: @DavidHarris good point, changing it to 5 doesn't fix it. Using raw arrays (not going through `tf.data`) also shows the same behaviour.

Comment: OK, the only other thing I can see that looks like it scales with data size is the source numpy array, if it contains all data. There are ways of avoiding having all that in memory if it's the problem - e.g. using tf.data.Dataset.from_generator or tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset. But I'm speculating a little, maybe there's some other issue.

Comment: @DavidHarris the thing that puzzles me is that none of that should be in vRAM, and there is plenty of RAM left. Training on CPU alone works.

Comment: Have you solved it? Same problem here.

Comment: @Foreen no change. Reported as a bug, but the TF team is having trouble replicating it... because in Colab there is more vRAM than RAM. [Here it is](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/16997)